# How to store radio button value from recyclerview in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I am using `recyclerview` in my app to display employee .I have radio buttons inside the cards which i need to select (i.e Present and absent) and store the date where only if employee is absent 
My database to store the value would be like

```
Attendance Table 
A_id (p.k)
Emp_id (f.k)
Dates (date value)
```

So i don't know how to get values of radio button from card and enter in database for that selected employee id (lets assume i have `emp_id` retrieve from my databases so that i can pass it while insertion of attendance data)

I have specified a mark image button above the `recyclerview`  so that it can take the values of selected radio button(which is absent) and stored it in database .
Can anyone help me with how to get selected radio button from card view (there are many entries i.e many cards ) using `onclicklistener` of image 
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

In your recyclerviews adapter,
in the view holder class, set on check listener for the checkbox.
inside the listener, update the dataset you are passing to the recycler view adapter.

So you now have the dataset with details about which boxes have been checked.

now write a public method,say getUpdatedData(), inside the adapter class to return the data to your main activity.

Now in your imageviews onclick listener, call this method to get the data set. Iterate through the data and you will get which buttons are checked.

Hope you get what I'm trying to say

I could show you some code, if you had posted your code.